# Symfony2 and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I just came across Twitter Bootstrap today, on SO. I have **skimmed** through some online tutorials and if my understanding so far is correct, using the TB essentially consists of:

1. Downloading TB, extracting CSS files etc
2. Referencing the required CSS, JS files in your HTML doc and using the defined CSS patterns

I want to use Twitter Bootstrap with Symfony2. Given my understanding of how to use TB I thought it would be relatively easy to use it with Symfony, so I was quite suprised to see that there are (actually several) Bundles to use with Symfony.

So my questions are:

1. Why is a Bundle needed to use Twitter Bootstrap with Symfony2? - will the method I explained above not work (i.e. adding the references directly in a twig template)?
2. Since there are several Twitter Bootstrap Bundles available (at last count there are 3), which is the easiest to use (it has to be one that is actively supported with recent commits, and not a dead project)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm pretty sure these Bundles are great, but they have advantages and drawbacks. You could also use TB without a Bundle directly in your project. That's what I personally do, that way:

- git clone TB in web/ (to get latest updates and keep updated)
- I directly call bootstrap.less in my twig templates with Assetic and the less filter. That way, I can create my own .less files that @imports TB and use their astonishing mixins for example.

It's really powerful this way. Coupled with yui-compressor, when I use Assetic in no-debug mode, all my js and less files are compiled into one single .css output and one single .js output. And you could benefit from all TB functionalities, in .less, not .css

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. You are a life saver!. I was tearing my hair out, as to which direction to go. When you have a moment, could you please elaborate a little bit more?. Small snippet showing a twig template using Assetic, yui-compressor etc, required config settings etc. will be superb, as a lot of this is new technology for me. Thanks

Comment: This cookbook should be perfect for you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html ;)

Comment: Some of the bundles are useful, even if you use bootstrap directly.  You can, for example, borrow the form themes in Twig and use them directly in your project.

Comment: Hey, I am doing something similar, the difference is: I've put the bootstrap inside BundleFooBar/Resources/public thus I have it inside the web foder after an assets:install but, I have a minor issue and needed to add the stylesheet link separated from bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css, my issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893873/assetic-isnt-merging-bootstrap-css-and-bootstrap-responsive-css

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 major bundles that provides symfony integration with Twitter Bootstrap:

- [MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle)
- [BcBootstrapBundle](http://knpbundles.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle)

In my opinion:

**MopaBootstrapBundle** is more complex, provides its own layout structure (of cause you can create your own too) and lot of defined functionality, extra assetic, forms and other integration

**BcBootstrapBundle** is more simple and much more clear you use your own layout structure and there is a lot of defined functionality, extra assetic, forms and other integration too

**dont use any intergtaion bundle** also is an option, but you loose integration with forms, assetic, less and so (as @Acyra mentioned in his comment)

I prefer to use BcBootstrapBundle with its extra integration functionality and use my own custom layout structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Twitter Boostrap (TB) to only add css to your project. And then, you have a starting point to do something more visual than started from scratch. As you described in the first part.

But, you can also retrieve more interesting stuff from a Bundle which handle template integration with TB. For example:

- [having a default layout that set some basic column](https://github.com/toaotc/ToaTwitterBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig)
- [integration for crud generation](https://github.com/toaotc/ToaTwitterBootstrapBundle/tree/master/Resources/skeleton/crud/views)
- [having a basic form element](https://github.com/ruian/TwitterBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_v2.html.twig)

For example, with symfony 1.4 (*I know this post talks about sf2*), you have a plugin that can add a new theme to the admin generator to have a nice TB integration instead of the default. I know there is no official admin generator in sf2 but it can be used for CRUD.

One other thing that can be true since symfony 1.0, not all bundles are very well implemented, developped, maintained, tested, documented, etc .. (except thoses from the core team (FOS* Bundle, Doctrine, Propel, etc ..)). So I recommend you to test them all, see if one of them fit your need, otherwise take inspiration to improve them (they are almost all on github) or build your own.

And btw, there are [many Bundle](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=twitter) ..

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE to Symfony and Bootstrap:** Symfony always seems a little behind in the details of their documentation so here's an update on Symfony.  Version 2.6 and greater now includes basic integration with Twitter Bootstrap.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

Hopefully this saves someone time and can get it to work as they explain in the Symfony documentation above!

Comment: but what about inside 3rd party bundles? like Fos UserBundle

Comment: According to Symfony's documentation, incorporating Bootstrap should be as easy as extending the theme's view, or embedding one of the snippets in these docs.  Since Bootstrap is a library mostly of JS and CSS, any bundle should be able to access these assets.

"The new form theme comes in two flavors: normal layout and horizontal layout. To apply this new theme to all the forms of your application, use the following configuration:

{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{# {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %} #}"