# Assetic isn't merging bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, assetic

I am using Symfony2 and Assetic.

The assetic runs fine on dev (debug = true), however it is not merging the bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css when I run the dump for prod (debug = false).

Any thoughts? 
Tkx

Answer (score 0):

In order to temporary solve the issue, I needed to put the bootstrap.css outside the twig ({% stylesheets), example:

```html
 /* Instead of: */
{% stylesheets 'bundles/foobar/css/*' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}


/* I am doing: */
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/bundles/foobar/css/bootstrap.css'>
{% stylesheets
'bundles/foobar/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'
'bundles/foobar/css/chosen.css'
'bundles/foobar/css/custom.css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```